# Xamarin forms: Keyboard is not hiding when click background in xamarin forms IOS

Tags: ios, scroll, xamarin.forms, keyboard

In the normal case of xamarin forms ios app, the keyboard is hiding when taps on the background. Also, scrolling works perfectly when the keyboard is on.

**But when the page contains listview, the keyboard is not closing when background tap and scrolling is not working in the same case.**

How can I fix this issue? I need to close the keyboard when clicking the background and need scrolling feature. Error screenshot in android:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Cause:**

When the listview is scrolling.The touch event will be blocked.

**Solution:**

You can set the keyboard dismiss when you start scroll the listView.You should implement it in CustomRenderer.Refer the following code.

> in Forms

```
namespace xxx
{
  public class MyListView:ListView
  {
    public MyListView()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

> in xxx.iOS

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyListView),typeof(MyiOSListView))] 
namespace xxx.iOS
{
 public class MyiOSListView:ListViewRenderer
  {
    public MyiOSListView()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            Control.KeyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag;
        }

    }
 }
}
```

> in xaml

```
 <local:MyListView>
    <local:MyListView.ItemsSource>
      ...  
    </local:MyListView.ItemsSource>>
 </local:MyListView>
```

Comment: What change will come on the xaml part?

Comment: I have android and UWP projects, getting error on android project

Comment: I am testing the ios app in simulator, keyboard is not showing on simulator, is there any way to check this feature with keyboard?

Comment: Hardware->keyboard->connect hardware keyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184130/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: Hi, please share the code available to do the same logic in Android if any with renderers for xamarin.forms